# UIActivityViewController issue in attaching word or Excel files

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using UIActivityviewcontroller in iOS app. it is working fine for pdf file as attachment but does not working when I am attaching word or excel file. I am using below code

```
    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:<Server fileUrl>];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"FileName", pdfData] applicationActivities:nil];
     [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

does anyone have idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use **UIDocumentInteractionController**

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *pdfData = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileNameStr]];
[pdfData presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Check here for more detail. [UIDocumentInteractionController_class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/)

Comment: it works for local files only, file need to downloaded in temp first, However I tried with it but it does attaching the file.